# Keep getting Illegal start of type error, how can I correct this and move forward?

Tags: java

Part of my code is below; I am unable to compile because of a constant `illegal start of type` error (on the line of the `if` statement). What I can do to change it?

```
public class Job
{

    boolean jobsCompleted = false;
    Job firstJob = getCurrentJob();
    String jobName = firstJob.getName();
    int jobDuration = firstJob.getDuration();
    if (!myJob.isEmpty()&& jobDuration > 0 && jobDuration <= myTotalDuration) 
    //this is where i am getting the error, highlighting red before the 'if' statement.
```

Comment: Isn't that Java? You've tagged it as JavaScript!

Comment: This is definitely not a valid javascript.

Comment: if `myJob` is a Java class, it should have been called `MyJob`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, i didn't realise i clicked on Javascript instead of Java.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some of that code into a method, as you can only have an `if` inside a method.

for example

```
public class AClass {
    void aMethod() {
        if( true == true ) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```